# Can't delete an object with a certained value inside an array in firebase/firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I am a building a member system and every member has an array points.
But I can't seem to delete an object when a person tries to remove this point.

```
users(collection) -
 member(document) -
      "id" . --fields
      "username" . --fields
      "userevents" . --array
         [0]
            "id"
            "date"
            "price"
         [1]
            "id"
            "date"
            "price"




deletePoint = (userId, pointId, date, price) => {
    let docRef = this.db.collection('users').doc(userId);
    docRef.update({
      points: this.db.FieldValue.arrayRemove({
        date: date,
        id: pointId,
        price: price,
      }),
    });
  };
```

this.db is firebase.firestore()

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#static-arrayremove) when you're using arrayRemove you have to point directly to the field that you want to remove, not the content within said field so your example would become:

```
deletePoint = (userId, pointId, date, price) => {
    let docRef = this.db.collection('users').doc(userId);
    docRef.update({
      points: this.db.FieldValue.arrayRemove("0"),
    });
  };
```

And this will delete the whole content of the field (id, date, price) with an index of 0.